# DefaultHttpRequest not capturing # query string

Tags: c#, oauth, httprequest

I have an api that is being redirected to with a request with the following format:

```
https://localhost:4200/test#access_token=....
```

This is not something that I control and is unfortunately not your standard `&` query string. As a result when I try to extract the `access_token` value from the request I cannot find it.

I am using a `HttpContext` and the `Request` property:

```cs
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request; // No properties contain the access_token
}
```

Are there any other solutions to retrieve the original (un-sanitised) URL that was requested.

Comment: I don't think you can. `#` is not sent to the server (only used by the browser) so you won't be able to get those values. Use query string `?` instead

Comment: @haldo thanks for the response - there are plenty of things to try however none of them have solved my issue. However, reading the thread I think that it is a problem that cannot easily be solved without additional work - thanks for your help